how can i close a Get overlay in flutter?
I have an async function in my application and the user should wait unlit the operation is completed but there should be a button that cancels the operation and restest the operation in the app
the problem is when i use getx's overley it is fine but the cancel btn does not work i searched every where and still nothing
await Get.showOverlay(asyncFunction: () async {
      //-------------------Example for the operation----------
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    }, loadingWidget: Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      type: MaterialType.transparency,
      elevation: 0,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('working on...',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 20,fontFamily: 'Sans',),),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
          CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.blue),
          BtnWidget(text: 'cancle', icon: Assets.svg.cancelSvgrepoCom, onPressed: () {
            Get.back();
            restartsteps();
          })
        ],
      ),
    ));


i appreciate any help
i used Get.back() but it goes to previous page and the overlay is still open untill the operation finishes
i used
Get.back(closeOverlays: true); and
Get.close(1),
nothing worked yet

Future are not stoppable in middle of execution.
You can combine Timer with Completer to complete it from your Timer and await on Completer.future like this:
final Completer<bool> completer = Completer();
late Timer timer;
    
await Get.showOverlay(asyncFunction: () 
         async {
          timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
          completer.complete(true);
          });
          await completer.future;
        },
        loadingWidget: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          type: MaterialType.transparency,
          elevation: 0,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'working on...',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontFamily: 'Sans',
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.blue),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  timer.cancel();
                  completer.complete(true);
                },
                child: Text("cancel"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));


It worked!
Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it!
I used Future.delayed instead of timer and that worked too.

Future.delayed may work instead of timer but you cant stop Future.delayed  while calling completer.complete(true) in cancel button.You may get an error Log as completer.complete(true) is invoked already if you press cancel button.
